# Why does TLS 1.3 (Client/Server) Hello require a random number?

Tags: tls

Why does TLS 1.3 (Client/Server) Hello require a random number? Wouldn't a sequence number also work?

I do understand that a sequence number is predictable but I don't see why this would be a problem in TLS 1.3.

Comment: Please indicate what you **do** understand about what the client_random is used for in TLS. Indicate the version number of the TLS version(s) that you are targeting. And please spell check the title before you submit again. The question will remain closed until these changes are made using [edit].

Comment: Note: a sequence number is predictable. A random number is not. In some protocols, that's an issue. But we need to know exactly which to formulate an answer.

Comment: The problem with sequence numbers is mainly that they require state to be maintained. TBH I don't expect much problems if you would replace the randoms with sequence numbers or - more specifically - nonces; the problem lies in ensuring that they actually **are** nonces. This is the start of the handshake - the nonce needs to be bound with a session, you cannot use a message counter for this nonce.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does TLS 1.3 (Client/Server) Hello require a random number?

There are two ways to interpret this question.

The first is "what are the reasons why the TLS 1.3 RFC requires the client random value and the first 24 bytes of the server random value (in the Hello messages) to be, well, random?"

Well, I believe it's historic legacy.  That was part of the design of SSLv2; while there have been a *lot* of changes between SSLv2 and TLS 1.3, this part has remained pretty much the same (likely because people were pretty sure that it wasn't a security issue).

The second way of interpreting the question would be "what awful things would happen if we decided to to make them predictable, for example, a sequence number?".

The answer (as far as I can see) is "not much".  The client and server random values are there to prove liveness; a sequence number would prove liveness just as well as a random number.  The only issue I can see is reboots; if the client reboots and starts back at the same sequence number, you no longer have the liveness proof.

Of course, having the client and the server send "random values" makes it easy for a malicious implementation to exfiltrate information (e.g. the private keys).  On the other hand, there are lots of other ways for a malicious implementation to do that (e.g. selecting the DH/ECDH private values in a way which is predictable), and so covering up this one place wouldn't be that big of a deal...

On the other hand, generating random numbers is cheap; certainly cheaper than the DH or ECDH operations involved; and so I can see little reason not to go with the RFC requirements...